# Using Spring transaction management in a Vertx application

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-transactions, vert.x

While writing a simple web-app POC I would like to benefit from both - [Vertx](http://vertx.io/) non-blocking, event-driven nature and [Spring](https://spring.io/) declarative transaction management.

My application interacts with a relational DB so I need to manage transactions.
The [Spring Framework’s declarative transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained) is made possible with Spring aspect-oriented programming. Naturally I would like to annotate my service layer with the [@Transactional annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html). So far so good, but now Vertx non-blocking nature kicks in. My DAO is running some blocking calls (DB queries) which I would like to run using [vertx worker verticle](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#worker_verticles) which is executed using a thread from the worker pool (won’t block any event loops).

So as I imagine it I got 2 Vertx verticles managed as spring beans. One verticle running my service layer, communicating via [vertx event-bus](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html) with my second (worker) verticle running my DAO blocking code.

I'm wondering weather spring transaction should work well with this asynchronous flow. Is there any example for such working implementation (assuming this is a valid practice, is this?)?

Searching the net I've found [this](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples/spring-example) and [that](http://www.javaadvent.com/2015/12/reactive-programming-with-vert-x.html) but both don't demonstrate the use of Spring transactions.

Any ideas/thoughts?

Comment: Do you know you can [manage transactions with Vert.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41017843/using-spring-transaction-management-in-a-vertx-application) too ?

Comment: No, I didn't, I'de love to see some examples/documentation, I think you posted the wrong link there.

Comment: Ooops... :) Yes, here it is: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sql-common/java/#_using_transactions

Comment: Its been a while, but were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @gammay - Not quite yet